# JavaMail Hotmail setFlag not working

Tags: jakarta-mail, pop3, hotmail

Also, do you know if setting flags is possible in hotmail via javamail? I cannot get the following to work:

```
//...create connection to hotmail

Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
Message messages[] = folder.getMessages();
messages[0].setFlag(Flags.Flag.SEEN, true);   //this doesn't work
folder.close(true);
store.close();
```

No error is thrown, but the message still appears unread in my hotmail inbox.

Comment: 1) Do you close store and folders with folder.close(true); store.close();?
2) From javadoc: This will result in a MessageChangedEvent being delivered to any MessageChangedListener registered on this Message's containing folder. Do your listeners receive any events?

Comment: (code updated) that didn't work

Answer (score 2):

You really need to read the javadocs for the [com.sun.mail.pop3 package](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/pop3/package-summary.html).  The POP3 protocol doesn't support the things you're trying to do.